# I am able to compile a JUnit program through ant build.xml but while executing it I am getting NoClassFounder exception

Tags: java, ant, junit4

I am new to JUnit and ant. I doubt whether my build.xml is correct. I am able to generate .class file through compile tag in target. But I am not able to execute the file. When I try to execute the `test` tag in the below script. I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, this is the where I got stuck.

Same program works in eclipse IDE fine.. But not able to execute through ant only

I have verified classpath for java and ant multiple times. It is fine too

I am trying to sort this out from past three days..But still problem persists..

Someone please help me

```
<target name="compile" description = "Compiling java code">
    <javac srcdir="D:/AntBuilder/src" destdir="D:/AntBuilder/build" classpath= "D:/AntBuilder/dist/lib" includeantruntime="true" /> 
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile" description="Execute Unit Tests" >
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <formatter type="xml" /> 
    <test name="automation.LogInTest" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="D:/AntBuilder/dist/lib"/>
            <pathelement location="D:/AntBuilder/build"/>
        </classpath>    
    </junit>
</target>
```

Vamshi G

Comment: Which class is not found? Show stacktrace!

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: automation.LogInTest

automation is package. And I have written class name LogInTest in it

Comment: And your class names `LogInTest` in the package `automation`? You see the compiles class in one of the Folder `D:/AntBuilder/dist/lib` or `D:/AntBuilder/build`

Comment: Hi Jens,

My source code is present in srcdir .class file generated successfully in D:/AntBuilder/build nd I have placed junit jar file in D:/AntBuilder/dist/lib

Comment: Are there any "caused by" exceptions in the stacktrace? If not, double check if `D:/AntBuilder/build/automation/LogInTest.class` exists. Copy paste the name to check for typos.

Comment: PFB exception obtained


<error message="org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver"
        type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

        org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)

        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out the issue now.

Problem lies with adding jar files in lib folder. Along with selenium-java-2.41.0.jar file we need to download one more jar file.. selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

As per the stacktrace, it is not able to locate WEbDriver.exe. Download the file and place it where all jars are located.

Comment: Hi Neha,

Thanks for the info.. I have added the executable file for the browser also..